# Как узнать ip пользователя в telegram-боте?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

У меня есть бот, с помощью которого идёт трафик на cpa-сеть. Единственная инфа, которая совпадает у пользователей в боте и в сети - это ip-адрес. Для детальной статистики и когортного анализа мне нужно узнать ip-адреса юзеров бота, как это сделать? Также буду рад другим предложениям как мне привязать конкретное действие, отмеченное в сра-сети, к конкретному пользователю бота!